# Get different results by using date and DateTime

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I can't undestand why do I get a different results by using date() function and DateTime object. I'm on Mac.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Sofia');

echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s'); // 2015-04-02 01:18:59 correct

$date = new DateTime('@'.time());  
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');  // 2015-04-01 10:18:59 offset
```

**Edit**

Tried `$date = new DateTime('@'.time(), new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia'));`
no effect

Comment: You must set date zone `date_default_timezone_set("zone")`, see this documentation please: [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: @andalm already tried that as can be seen in my question.

Comment: Ok, Try setting datetimezone, see this http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php

Comment: I did it. Please read Rizier123's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date_default_timezone_set()` doesn't effect the `DateTime` class so you have to set it with the methods from `DateTime` like this:

```
$date = new DateTime("@".time());  
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d h:i:s') . "<br>";
```

**Side Note:**

Normally you could also do this:

```
$date = new DateTime("@".time(), new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia'));
```

But since you use a timestamp this is not possible for some reason.

This is already in the bug tracker here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40743

Comment: Thanks but why It doesn't work like that  `date = new DateTime('@'.time(), new DateTimeZone('Europe/Sofia'));`

Comment: @MZON I can't tell you that, it's just like this, maybe they will fix it

Comment: @MZON updated answer with the bug tracker link for this